# Programmatically select newly-created option with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I’m using jQuery 1.10.3 to dynamically add an `<option>` to a `<select>` list. The relavant code looks like this:

```
option = '<option value="' + response.id + '">' + response.title + '</option>';
select.append(option);
```

However, I’m having trouble finding out how to dynamically select this newly-created option. I would have thought something like…

```
select.append(option).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

…Would work, but it didn’t.

Is this possible and if so, how so?

Comment: Did you try `option = '<option selected value="' + response.id + '">' + response.title + '</option>';` (Note the selected attribute)

Comment: @Cherniv You are trying to set `selected` property on select and but it should be set on option.

Comment: You are setting the `<select>` to have have the attribute selected, not the option, hence the issue.

Comment: @Vega What happens if I insert multiple options during one session though? I’ll have multiple `<option>` tags with the `selected` attribute present.

Comment: @MartinBean You are right, it seems the attributes are set on all options.

Comment: if you insert multiple the last one should be the newest one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because the focus is still on the select.  try something like

```
$(option).appendTo(select).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

[Source](http://jsfiddle.net/j9d2G/)

Comment: That did it, thank you! I’ll accept the answer in 10 minutes when Stack Overflow allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
option = '<option selected="selected" value="' + response.id + '">' + response.title + '</option>';
select.append(option);
```

Update: after reading your comment I believe this isn't a multi select list. In that case you'll have to do this before the above code to have only one selected option:

```
$("select option").each(function(){
   $(this).removeAttr("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this - (*you were setting attr selected to the `select` not to the `option`*)

```
select.append($(option).prop('selected', true));
```